# Laplace transform via complex analysis

Tags: complex-analysis, laplace-transform, contour-integration

Let $Y(s) = \frac{2e^{-s}}{s(s^2 + 3s + 2)}$. Then the inverse Laplace transform is
\begin{align}
y(t) &= \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\gamma-i\infty}^{\gamma+i\infty}\frac{2e^{s(t - 1)}}{s(s^2 + 3s + 2)}ds\\
&= \lim_{s\to 0}\frac{2e^{s(t - 1)}}{s^2 + 3s + 2} + \lim_{s\to - 1}\frac{2e^{s(t - 1)}}{s(s + 2)} + \lim_{s\to -2}\frac{2e^{s(t - 1)}}{s(s + 1)}\\
&= 1 - 2e^{-(t-1)} + e^{-2(t - 1)}\\
&= (e^{-(t-1)} - 1)^2\\
&\neq e^{-2(t-1)}(e^{t-1} - 1)^2\mathcal{U}(t - 1)\tag{solution}
\end{align}
The actual solution was obtained from Mathematica. Where did I go astray?

---

I have, also, come to the conclusion that whenever there is a shift in the exponential $s(t-a)$ where $a\in\mathbb{R}$, we have to multiple by $\mathcal{U}(t-a)$ but I think I should be able to acquire the unit step from the integration, correct?

Comment: What you've written makes little sense. First this is not the inverse Laplace transform, unless you are integrating along the imaginary axis. Otherwise, the integral you've written doesn't converge since $e^{2s(t-1)}$ will blow up either at $s=\pm\infty$ depending on the sign of $(t-1)$.

Comment: I strongly suggest you carefully examine the formula in your link. It is very different from what you've written. Again, you need to integrate on the *imaginary* axis. Your integral as written *does not converge*.

Comment: The integral for the inverse Laplace transform involves integration along a vertical line $(c-i\infty,c+i\infty)$ in the complex plane with all the poles of $F(s)$ to its left. [Moreover, as Alex R. says, the integral as you've written it is divergent.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem.
\begin{align}
y(t) &= \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\gamma-i\infty}^{\gamma+i\infty}\frac{2e^{s(t - 1)}}{s(s^2 + 3s + 2)}ds\\
&= \lim_{s\to 0}\frac{2e^{s(t - 1)}}{s^2 + 3s + 2} + \lim_{s\to - 1}\frac{2e^{s(t - 1)}}{s(s + 2)} + \lim_{s\to -2}\frac{2e^{s(t - 1)}}{s(s + 1)}
\end{align}
Due to the exponential term, we need the real part of $s$ to be $\text{Re}(s)>1$. So this introduces the $\mathcal{U}(t-1)$
\begin{align}
&=1\mathcal{U}(t-1) - 2e^{-(t-1)}\mathcal{U}(t-1) + e^{-2(t-1)}\mathcal{U}(t-1)\\
&=\mathcal{U}(t-1)(1-2e^{-(t-1)}+e^{-2(t-1)})\\
&=\mathcal{U}(t-1)(-e^{-(t-1)}+1)^2
\end{align}