# Inverse Laplace transform shifting error

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

I am doing the inverse Laplace transform of the function: $\frac{e^{-s}}{s-1}$.

I am solving and receiving the answer: $e^t\mathcal{U}(t-1)$, however the correct answer is $e^{t-1}\mathcal{U}(t-1).$

Im failing to see where the $-1$ in the exponential is coming from, and I have attempted several times.

I am using the equation $\mathcal{L}^{-1}[e^{-as}F(s)] = \mathcal{U}(t-a)f(t-a)$;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$F(s)={1\over s-1}\implies f(t)=e^t$ so using the theorem you want $u(t-a)\color{blue}{f(t-a)}=u(t-1)f(t-1)=u(t-1)e^{t-1}$

Answer (score 2):

I prefer to use the definition then tables to solve the inverse Laplace transform.
\begin{align}
\mathcal{L}^{-1}\{e^{-s}/(s - 1)\} &= \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\gamma - i\infty}^{\gamma + i\infty}\frac{e^{-s}e^{st}}{s- 1}ds\\
&= \sum\text{Res}\\
&= \lim_{s\to 1}(s-1)\frac{e^{s(t-1)}}{s-1}\\
&= e^{t - 1}\mathcal{U}(t - 1)
\end{align}
Then from the definition, we see where the $t - 1$ comes from.

Just to note, I don't know why the unit step comes into play when we have a shift. I have asked a question on it [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1047416/laplace-transform-via-complex-analysis) 10 days agos but no answer yet.

Comment: To understand the step function result, you have to understand the nature of how the integration contour is deformed in the complex plane.  When you close the contour to the left, you enclose the pole and you get the residue at the pole...but, the integral about the semicircular piece of the contour has to vanish as the radius increases without bound, and this is only true when $t \gt 1$.  Otherwise, you have to close to the right, where there are no poles so the integral, and the ILT, is zero.  That said, please refrain from posting answers when you don't understand them.

Comment: @RonGordon there was a benefit from not refraining. I was able to have someone (you) explain the situation which I have been furiously googling for days.